# What's wrong with the Javascript code?

Tags: javascript, jquery

What's wrong with the custom.js file of my template file. It's using jQuery easing plugin, Vegas background image plugin and jQuery Countdown. As soon as I add the vegas code, the timer didn't show up. Please help me in fixing the code.

```
$(function () {
    $('.page-scroll a').bind('click', function (event) {
        var $anchor = $(this);
        $('html, body').stop().animate({
            scrollTop: $($anchor.attr('href')).offset().top
        }, 1500, 'easeInOutExpo');
        event.preventDefault();
    });

    // Image background
    $.vegas({
        src: 'assets/images/bg1.jpg'
    });

    $.vegas('overlay', {
        src: 'assets/images/06.png'
    });


    var description = {
        weeks: "weeks",
        days: "days",
        hours: "hours",
        minutes: "minutes",
        seconds: "seconds"
    };

    // year/month/day
    $('#countdown').countdown('2015/6/12', function (event) {
        $(this).html(event.strftime(
            '<div class="countdown-section"><b>%w</b> <span>' + description.weeks + '</span> </div>' +
            '<div class="countdown-section"><b>%d</b> <span>' + description.days + '</span> </div>' +
            '<div class="countdown-section"><b>%H</b> <span>' + description.hours + '</span> </div>' +
            '<div class="countdown-section"><b>%M</b> <span>' + description.minutes + '</span> </div>' +
            '<div class="countdown-section"><b>%S</b> <span>' + description.seconds + '</span> </div>'
        ));
    });
});
```

Comment: do some basic troubleshooting, such as check for errors thrown

Comment: And tidy up your code.

Comment: Stack Overflow isn't a substitute for debugging.

Comment: I'm using Sublime Text 2 for coding, and fairly new to Javascript. Pardon my silly questions. Please recommend few sources so that I can get my basics cleared. Thanks for the timely help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing your closing `});`.

You also had two `$(document).ready()` calls - `$(function() {})` is just short hand.

Best to invest in a auto formatter and/or run your code through a linter when in doubt - checkout this repo for some karma+grunt magic - https://github.com/karma-runner/grunt-karma.

Comment: If it solved your problem could you mark it as the answer? :) Glad to have helped.